# Changing elements in free PrestaShop theme

Tags: javascript, themes, prestashop

I am new to prestaShop and have a few simple questions.

I've chosen this free template: https://ets-demos.com/theme/furniture/en/?fbclid=IwAR2r1GKUUyK5cch374ZhjOtzKBB3ZgGPQ7Uzct21Z7rIP89Atohle_81YGw

Can i change (without coding) the search tool, to be just a small rectangle below the magnifying glass instead of fullscreen?

Can I add facebook/msg/ig fixed references on the left?

If it is possible, or possible only with coding, please let me know.

I am asking these questions here, because the owner of the theme isn't supporting free templates with free technical support :P

Did any of PrestaShop users had a problem with installing it on simple home.pl simple start hosting? When the prestaShop is being installed on domain, it stops at 8% and failure to search file pops out.

Best regards, Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, without coding, these cannot be solved.

However, if you don’t have experience in coding, it won’t be an easy thing to do, as it also depends on the theme where to modify and what. These are not global things that apply equally to all themes.

> Did any of PrestaShop users had a problem with installing it on simple
> home.pl simple start hosting? When the prestaShop is being installed
> on domain, it stops at 8% and failure to search file pops out.

What exactly error is displayed?
Your hosting provider may not meet all of the conditions required to run PrestaShop.
For better performance, you may want to choose a hosting provider that has hosting optimized for PrestaShop.
https://digital.com/best-web-hosting/prestashop/